# PDOStatement::fetch returns false

Tags: php, pdo, fetch

I'm having some troubles with the fetch-method. Here's the code:

```
        $stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO x (name) VALUES (:username)");
        $stmt->bindParam(':username', $username);
        $result = $stmt->execute();
        if ($result == '1') {
            $id = $stmt->fetch();
            return $id;
        }
```

The query is executed and data inserted, and $result is '1'. However, when I try to fetch the result, it's returning false.

Any tips?

Comment: You can't fetch from `INSERT` queries

Comment: Thanks. Sorry for the stupid question. So I guess the best way to do it is by doing a SELECT-query after you've inserted?

Comment: Depends on what you're trying to do exactly.  You want the insert ID?  You can `PDO::lastInsertId` in MySQL (apparently it's not dependable, but I've never had a problem with it).  That or SELECT `LAST_INSERT_ID()`.

Comment: Marked as correct answer. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `$db->lastInsertId()` in MySQL (apparently it's not dependable, but I've never had a problem with it). Either That or run another query: `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()` and fetch that.

Answer (score -1):

If you're wanting to fetch the number of rows inserted, follow it with this query:

```
$rows_inserted = $db->query("SELECT FOUND_ROWS()")->fetchColumn();
```

Comment: Don't use PDO as a fluent interface.  You aren't guaranteed that query() returns an object.  It could return `false` on error.